# Mount ZFS dump from a file in Linux

Tags: linux, mount, snapshot, zfs

I have a NAS that does regular snapshots. 
I was toying around with the snapshots, planning to eventually store them in the cloud.

I create a file from a snapshot using zfs send and redirecting the output:

```
zfs send snapshot_name > backup.snapshot
```

If I want to inspect the snapshot, is there a way to mount the snapshot file itself?

Thanks

Mirko

Comment: `zfs send` doesn't produce a snapshot, it produces sequence of _replay records_ that can be used to reproduce it. However, you can access `.zfs/snapshots` subdir on your source system or perform `zfs recv` to rebuild it from scratch

Comment: Thanks! so the only way to see the files outside the source system would be to cat the snapshot file that I created and pipe it in zfs receive pointing to a new pool?

Answer (score 1):

ZFS doesn't support that. If you really want to validate a snapshot, I recommend that you create another ZFS pool in a different host and/or a virtual machine to issue a `zfs send` and `zfs receive`.

For example, consider this setup:

- A production ZFS pool (`tank`) running on a host;
- A virtual machine with another ZFS pool (`tank-backup`) that acts as a snapshot validation point;
- `root` SSH access is permitted using SSH key pair authentication.

On the production ZFS pool, if a snapshot is created (e.g. `snap1`), you can transfer it to the virtual machine in order to validate it. Also, by doing that, you will end up with a backup of this snapshot.

On the machine running the production ZFS pool, do the following:

- `sudo zfs send tank@snap1 | ssh root@zfs-backup-vm zfs receive tank-backup`

Additionally, if you want to work with incremental snapshots (e.g: you created the `snap2` snapshot and want to transfer it to the virtual machine):

- `sudo zfs send -I tank@snap1 tank@snap2 | ssh root@zfs-backup-vm zfs receive tank-backup`

About seeing the contents of ZFS snapshots, you can issue this command:

- `zpool set listsnapshots=off tank` [1]

This will enable the property `listsnapshots`. Considering that the ZFS pool `tank` is mounted at `/tank` and you have a ZFS dataset called `home`, all the snapshots for this ZFS pool and dataset will be accesible from this path:

- `/tank/home/.zfs/snapshot`

---

[1] https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gbiqe/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The following procedure works for me:

```
# zfs send tank/test@0830 > /bkups/test.0830
# zfs receive tank/test2@today < /bkups/test.0830
# zfs rename tank/test tank/test.old
# zfs rename tank/test2 tank/test
```

Of course, you can also access the `tank/test2` dataset directly.